# Ways to create a QDialog outside the main thread

Tags: qt, qthread

I am trying to create a client application in QT which requires both threads for processing and a variable amount of window instances. But I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to create a new window inside one of the processing thread. I understand that all ui elements must be created in the same thread as the QApplication class, but I need to be able to instantiate, or at least have a reference to a QDialog in another thread. 
Communicating between the thread and QDialog can be done using signals, I am not worried about this, but actually creating the window is another matter. I could use signals to tell the main thread to create an instance to the window, and then retrieve the pointer to it somehow, but to me that seems a bit to complicated and ugly. Is there a better way to accomplish such a task? To create a QDialog outside the main thread were the QApplication class exists? 
 
**Edit** : I have tried the Q_INVOKABLE method but it does not work across threads. I have created a view factory class which can create a QDialog of a type I specify and returns a pointer to it. This class has been instantiated in the main GUI thread and a reference to this class is sent to any worker threads. The problem is that, when a thread invokes the create method from the factory using Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection, the invoke method fails. If I change it to Qt::DirectConnection, the invoke method calls the right create method but in the current thread as the worker thread. 
 
My main function looks like this :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ViewFactory vFactory;

    vFactory.registerCreator(Util::W_CONNECT, new ConnectWindow::ConnectCreator());

    ClientApp app;

    if(!app.Initialize(&vFactory))
        return 0;

    app.start();
    a.exec();
    .............................

}
```

And my run function from the ClientApp thread looks something like this :

```
void ClientApp::run()
{
    QDialog * tmp = NULL;
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this->_vFactory, "create", Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
                        Q_RETURN_ARG(QDialog*, tmp), Q_ARG(int, 0));
}
```

Like I said, the invokeMothod will not fail if I change the connection type to Qt::DirectConnection, so the params are not the problem, but rather calling the method across a separate worker thread.

Comment: Solved it using Q_INVOKABLE. The reason why it failed is because when using Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection as a connection type you cannot pass Q_RETURN_ARG as a parameter, only simple arguments.

Comment: with Queued connections, the arg types are converted by Qt and stored in an event. In order for Qt to succeed with that, due to template magic, you need to register your types with Qt properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, signals (or just a dynamically callable method, using [`Q_INVOKABLE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE)) or an event is the way to go.

Note that, using [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) (with [`Qt::BlockedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)), you can call a function safely across threads and get a return value back without too much coding.

Answer (score 4):

You can only do Gui stuff in the gui thread. The obvious solution is for the worker thread to send a message to the gui thread = a signal in Qt terms.

If a worker thread needs to ask a question it should send a message to the gui thread and then block until it gets a signal back.

Comment: This is a great answer even after 10 years, it still helps very much.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `QObject::moveToThread` can solve this problem. This function moves event processing loop to another thread.

Example from Qt documentation:

```
myObject->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
```